# Short By option in one after next?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change Magento short by drop down in [image: this way]

Please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the file

> app/design/frontend/[your-package]/[your-theme]/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

if it is not present make a copy form the base/rwd theme and put it in you theme in a same folder structure

Then find code like this

```
<div class="sort-by">
    <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
    <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Sort By')) ?>">
        <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

So right now the **Sort By** input is as `select box`. make it as below

```
<div class="sort-by">
    <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
    <!-- Customization start-->
    <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
        <?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?>
            <span title="<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__($_order) ?></span>
        <?php else:?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__($_order) ?></a>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <!-- end-->
    <?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>" class="sort-by-switcher sort-by-switcher--desc" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Set Ascending Direction')) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>" class="sort-by-switcher sort-by-switcher--asc" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Set Descending Direction')) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Now you can **do your own style by CSS**

### Edit :

You can check a condition for price, refer below code

```
<?php if($_key == 'price'):?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Low %s', $_order) ?></a>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Hign %s',$_order) ?></a>
<?php else:?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__($_order) ?></a>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Also i need Price high to low, low to high, new and Popular

Comment: Thanks it working fine can plz tell me how to add Newest product

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237513/magento-sort-by-date-added

Comment: Hi  how to add a class based on selection

Comment: `<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> class="selected"<?php endif; ?>` inside the foreach

Comment: and you can get the current direction with this `$this->getCurrentDirection()`

Comment: can you plz Modify the code http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78603/how-to-add-a-class