# How to add a CSS class to selected option?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, css

Hi i used custom "sort by" option in `<a>` tag Now i want to add a CSS class name based on selection

```
<div class="sort-by_custom">

    <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>

        <?php if($_key == 'price'):?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Low %s', $_order) ?></a>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('High %s',$_order) ?></a>

<?php else:?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__($_order) ?></a> 
<?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

Please Suggest me.

Comment: you want to add a class where? what is "short by option in tag"?

Comment: yes if current selection is Low price then add class like wise

Comment: add a class WHERE?

Comment: i need to add some css for highlighting selected short by option so that i want to add class in <a> tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code, for add active class

```
<?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>

<?php if($_key == 'price'):?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>" <?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key) && $this->getCurrentDirection()=='asc'): ?> class="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__('Low %s', $_order) ?></a>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>" <?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key) && $this->getCurrentDirection()=='desc'): ?> class="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__('High %s',$_order) ?></a>

<?php else:?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>" <?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> class="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_order) ?></a> 
<?php endif;?>
```